# Create Print Template

Tags: c#, templates, xslt, printing

I have a web services application where I would like the users to be able to define print page templates with database field placeholder in my project.for this reason I 
have to provide environment for design template for my users.this templates must save in database,
then for print I get data from database and put it in placeholders.I found that "XSLT" can be usefully for this issue, but a big problem is Html result for XSLT.If There is any solution please let me know.

thanks in advance

Comment: XSLT can produce not only XML or HTML output, but also just plain text.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is: create a html file template, create field placeholder in it. When you need to print it, load data from database, replace the placeholder, create the html file, load it into webbrowser class (it does not have to have an UI). then print from there.

since it is html file, you can save it to database too.

it works great in one of our project which has the same requirement.

Comment: I don't want to export output as html.maybe its possible export as xml or even standard print format such as Microsoft xps!

Comment: you can print html file to file as xps. you do not have to export the generated html file, just use the webbrowser class's print feature.

Comment: I'm wonder if exist any way to generate XPS format directly from my web services method and send it to clients instead html!